# How can I remove Javascript files?

Tags: 6, javascript, theming

I wanted to remove some JavaScript files, since they conflict with my custom JavaScript on my mobile theme.

I tried with the following code, but it is not working in `hook_preprocess_page()`, which I think it really works in the first place; it's just that the original initialization of `$scripts` in page.tpl.php loads after `hook_preprocess_page()` alteration.

```
// Load all js scripts
    $scripts = drupal_add_js();

  // Unset all unnecessary scripts
    unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/ajax/ajax.js']);
    unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/contribs/mollom/mollom.js']);
    unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/contribs/views_slideshow/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js']);
    unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/contribs/views_slideshow/contrib/views_slideshow_singleframe/views_slideshow.js']);
    unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/contribs/views_slideshow/contrib/views_slideshow_thumbnailhover/views_slideshow.js']);
    unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/quicktabs/js/quicktabs.js']);
    unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/panels/js/panels.js']);
    unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/tipsy/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js']);
    unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/tipsy/javascripts/tipsy.js']);
    unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/boxes/boxes.js']);

    // Recreate the template variables

    $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);
```

How can I remove JavaScript files from the list of JavaScript files load when my theme is used?

Comment: Did you consider that you might need to rewrite your custom JS so that it does not conflict with Drupal's JS?  If you succeed in removing these scripts, there may be unintended consequences; a lot of Drupal's core and contrib modules use JS to enhance the UI. Have you read the (http://drupal.org/node/121997)[documentation on using javascript in Drupal 5 & 6]  to make sure you are building your JS correctly?

Comment: As far a I know every piece of code conforms the Drupal code standard. My issue here is I have desktop version and mobile version of the site with different theme fo each version. Most of the modules I'm using are packed with JS and CSS which these modules are intended for desktop site only 'coz the mobile site is just blogroll and dont need those files to be loaded every page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how solved my problem.

Found out that jquery_update uses `hook_theme_registry_alter()` to unset jquery in Drupal core and replace a new version of Jquery. So this `preprocess function` is being load after everything all. What I did is I created a `hook_theme_registry_alter()` and update the `weight` of the module higher than `jquery_update` module so I can override the `jquery_update_theme_registry_alter()`.

This `jquery_update_theme_registry_alter()` prevents any alteration in javascript which a big headache if you're working on some adjustments like in my case.

Code:

```
function my_module_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
    global $theme;

    // Only apply this code in mobile theme
    if($theme == 'myTheme') {
    //Attach the my_module_preprocess_page in the theme registry preprocess functions
      $theme_registry['page']['preprocess functions'][] = 'my_module_preprocess_page';
    }
}

function my_module_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

    // Perform the logic if either jQuery Update's jquery.js is newer than core's.
    if (variable_get('jquery_update_replace', TRUE)) {
        // Get an array of all the JavaScript files loaded by Drupal on this page.
        $scripts = drupal_add_js();

        // Replace jquery.js first.
        $new_jquery = array(jquery_update_jquery_path() => $scripts['core']['misc/jquery.js']);
        $scripts['core'] = array_merge($new_jquery, $scripts['core']);
        unset($scripts['core']['misc/jquery.js']);

        // Loop through each of the required replacements.
        foreach (jquery_update_get_replacements() as $type => $replacements) {
            foreach ($replacements as $find => $replace) {
                // If the file to replace is loaded on this page...
                if (isset($scripts[$type][$find])) {
                    // Create a new entry for the replacement file, and unset the original one.
                    $replace = JQUERY_UPDATE_REPLACE_PATH .'/'. $replace;
                    $scripts[$type][$replace] = $scripts[$type][$find];
                    unset($scripts[$type][$find]);
                }
            }
        }
        // Unset javascripts that is/are not needed in mobile theme
        unset($scripts['module']['sites/all/modules/boxes/boxes.js']);

            .....

        // Recreate the scripts variable
        $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help others. Please let me know if this approach is a violation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [AdvAgg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg). Has hooks for you to use and plays nicely with jquery update.